# script to make recursive descent along dropbox filestatus (CLI) recursive descent

Tags: python, bash, dropbox

The output of `dropbox filestatus` is a line-delimited list of files/directories with their current state. For example

```
dropbox filestatus 
dir a     up to date
dir b     syncing
dir c     up to date
```

If we cd to dir b then

```
dropbox filestatus 
file a     up to date
file b     syncing
dir p      syncing
dir q      up to date
```

I want a script that will descend along the syncing directories, while as it goes lists the files that are syncing in each directory.

Is this a task for bash? Or is obviously more a task for - say - python?

Answer (score 0):

I think bash can do it. Try this:

```sh
p=$(pwd) ; find . -type d \
| { while read d; do cd "$p/$d" ; dropbox filestatus ; done } | grep "syncing$"
```